# Visual studio 2013 express "you are unable to update your license in this application"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I cant update my license, it don't even ask me to sign in and when i close that the application is closed. I don't want to download other version. I need to use vs2013 only. can someone help
Here is the image of problem : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5808.jpg

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is no way for you to sign in to get a license. Could you please try running devenv /resetsettings from a developer command prompt in admin mode. Oh, close VS before running this command.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

Comment: This isn't a full answer but more of a suggestion.  It would be better as a comment.  See [answer]